# JQGrid successfunc and errorfunc both fire on save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Edit: Using JQGrid 4.5.4

I am using JQGrid for inline editing and have overridden the inline save button to trigger the function "SaveRow". By default, the "successfunc" function only receives the server response but I need the rowID as well. As such I've written "successfunc" to take an extra parameter:

```
function SaveRow(rowID)
{
    //Get grid
    var grid = $('#' + JQGridName);

    //Create save parameters
    saveParams = {
        "successfunc": function(response) {
            SaveRowSuccess(rowID, response);
        },
        "url": null,
        "extraparam": {},
        "aftersavefunc": null,
        "errorfunc": SaveRowFailure,
        "afterrestorefunc": null,
        "restoreAfterError": false,
        "mtype": "POST"
    };

    grid.jqGrid('saveRow', rowID, saveParams);
}
```

On a failed inline edit (code 500) "errorfunc" fires. The problem is that on a successful inline edit (code 200 ok) both "successfunc" and "errorfunc" fire.

I believe this is a problem with how I've formatted "successfunc". What is the proper way to pass the rowID to this function?

Comment: You wrote "I ... have overridden the inline save button". Which "inline save button" you mean? Do you use `formatter: "actions"` or `inlineNav`? How exactly you "overridden" it? Do you use `key: true` option for inline editing? In the case the user can save the editing row by pressing "Enter" key and no your custom save button handler will be called. Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: I'm using asp.NET JQGrid, so I've simply enabled inline editing by setting "EditActionIconsColumn" to true.

I've overridden it by iterating through the save buttons and setting the OnClick method to call an intermediate method which gets the rowID and then calls SaveRow. I use key: false, so the Enter button will not trigger the edit.

Added JQGrid version to original question.

Comment: just return 'true' from your 'successfunc'